# DAX Query to get average of a column within the same table

Tags: powerpivot, dax

We have a table named **MetricsTable** which has columns **A1** and **Group** simply.

We want to add a calculated column **AvgA1** to this table which calculates the average of column **A1** filtered by the value of **Group** . What should be our DAX query? The point is that we want to claculate the average from the values within the same table.

| id | A1| Group | AvgA1

| -- | --- | --- ------| ----

| 1  | 20  | Group1| 20

| 2  | 10  | Group2| 30

| 3  | 50  | Group2| 30

| 4  | 30  | Group2| 30

| 5  | 35  | Group3| 35

Regards

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Likely you should use a measure and put that measure into a pivot table's 'Values' section:

```
AverageA1:=
AVERAGE( Metrics[A1] )
```

Then it will be updated based on filter and slicer selections in the pivot table, and subtotaled appropriately across various dimension categories.

If it strictly needs to be a column in the table for reasons not enumerated in your question, then the following will work:

```
AverageA1 =
CALCULATE(
    AVERAGE( Metrics[A1] )
    ,ALLEXCEPT( Metrics, Metrics[Group] )
)
```

CALCULATE() takes an expression and a list of 0-N arguments to modify the filter context in which that expression is evaluated.

ALLEXCEPT() takes a table, and a list of 1-N fields from which to preserve context. The current (row) context in the evaluation of this column definition is the value of every field on that row. We remove the context from ALL fields EXCEPT those named in arguments 2-N of ALLEXCEPT(). Thus we preserve the row context of [Group], and calculate an average across the table where that [Group] is the same as in the current context.

Comment: Thanks ) Second one worked like a charm. We need to see the grouped averages in the same time with selected filter's average. That's why we can't use measure solution.

Comment: You can certainly see a group average with a filter's average in a measure. You can use the same ALLEXCEPT() in a measure.